# Adding Form Elements to a node for user input in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have my own content type made in my module. It has text and image fields.

I now want to add a form fields like radio box and a submit button so that when the node is rendered  the user can give their input. I unable to do  this.

1)
My first try failed when I tried adding a radio box when creating my content type.

```
simplequiz_radio11' => array(
'field_name' => 'simplequiz_radio11,
**'type'       => 'radio',**
```

What do I write in the type field besides text and image. I will like to mention again that the radio box needs to take the user input when the  node is rendered not in edit  mode.

2) I tried using drupal_get_forms and I am able to attach a form and its elements to the node using drupal_get_forms  but my node has many images(fields) and I need a form element for each image so its  not practical to use it this way. Below is my code:

```
function simplequiz_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode)
{  
$f = drupal_get_form('simplequiz_form', $node);
$f['#weight'] = 100;
$node->content['data_collection_form'] = $f;
}
```

This works fine but how can I do this for say 10 image fields ? It seems the first  option is better but  I  can't seem to get the right field type.

**// I managed to solve it as my logic was wrong I need to work with the formater and not the fields in drupal.**

```
function simplequiz_field_formatter_info() {
return array(

'simplequiz_example_field' => array(
  'label' => t('radio button on node'),
  'field types' => array('text'),
),
 'simplequiz_btn_field' => array(
  'label' => t('button on node'),
  'field types' => array('text'),
), 

);


}

/**
* Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
*/


function simplequiz_field_formatter_view($object_type, $object, $field, $instance,    
$langcode, $items, $display) {
switch ($display['type']) {
 case 'simplequiz_example_field':
  $element[0]['#type'] = 'markup';
  $element[0]['#markup'] = theme('simplequiz_example_field', array('value' => $items[0]   
['safe_value']));
  break;

case 'simplequiz_btn_field':
  $element[0]['#type'] = 'markup';
  $element[0]['#markup'] = theme('simplequiz_btn_field', array('value' => $items[0]  
['safe_value']));
  break;
 }
 return $element;
 }

/**
* Theme the example field.
 */
function theme_simplequiz_example_field($variables) {
return '<form><input type="radio" name="type" value="silver">Gold'
.$variables['value']. ' </br> <input type="radio" name="type" value="Gold"> Silver </br>   
</form>'

    ;
}

function theme_simplequiz_btn_field($variables) {
 return '<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Submit" name="op" id="edit-   
submit--2">'

    ;
}
```

Cheers,
Vishal

Comment: do you do this on the node view page or on the node edit page? if it's the edit page you can use a field with unlimited cardinality

Comment: I do  it on node view page. I solved it

Comment: Please post what you did to solve it and accept it as your solution so that others with a similar problem may find a solution.

Comment: I have  put the entire format code in my question for our reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**// I managed to solve it as my logic was wrong I need to work with the formater and not the fields in drupal.**

```
function simplequiz_field_formatter_info() {
return array(

'simplequiz_example_field' => array(
  'label' => t('radio button on node'),
  'field types' => array('text'),
),
 'simplequiz_btn_field' => array(
  'label' => t('button on node'),
  'field types' => array('text'),
), 

);


}

/**
* Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
*/


function simplequiz_field_formatter_view($object_type, $object, $field, $instance,    
$langcode, $items, $display) {
switch ($display['type']) {
 case 'simplequiz_example_field':
  $element[0]['#type'] = 'markup';
  $element[0]['#markup'] = theme('simplequiz_example_field', array('value' => $items[0]   
['safe_value']));
  break;

case 'simplequiz_btn_field':
  $element[0]['#type'] = 'markup';
  $element[0]['#markup'] = theme('simplequiz_btn_field', array('value' => $items[0]  
['safe_value']));
  break;
 }
 return $element;
 }

/**
* Theme the example field.
 */
function theme_simplequiz_example_field($variables) {
return '<form><input type="radio" name="type" value="silver">Gold'
.$variables['value']. ' </br> <input type="radio" name="type" value="Gold"> Silver </br>   
</form>'

    ;
}

function theme_simplequiz_btn_field($variables) {
 return '<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Submit" name="op" id="edit-   
submit--2">'

    ;
}
```

Cheers,
Vishal